# HTML and class selection options in the short code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

Example of some arbitrary/hypothetical shortcode →

```
function simplisto_some_function(){
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="newsletter class2">
            <h2><?php echo get_theme_mod('kirki_h'); ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo get_theme_mod('kirki_p'); ?></p>
        </div>
        //Some Other code
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('simplisto_some_function', 'simplisto_some_function');
```

My Requirement in the shortcode →

```
[simplisto_some_function]
```

I should have these options:

> 1. option whether to choose/use "class2"
> 2. option to eliminate `<h2>`
> 3. Option to eliminate `<p>`

`P.S.` → By default `<h2>` and `<p>` are selected.

is this possible or this is not a realistic expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass options from the shortcode to the function...

The shortcode

```
[simplisto useClass="1" useH2="0" useP="1"]
```

and then the function

```
function simplisto_function($atts){

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'useClass' => '',
        'useH2' => 1,
        'useP' => 1
    ), $atts ) );

$args = array(
    'useClass' => $useClass, 
    'useH2' => $useh2,
    'useP' => $usep

    );
    ob_start();
    //use your conditions in the html code
    ?>
    <div class="newsletter<?php $useClass==1 ? echo ' class2' : '' ?>">
        //the same for others 
    </div>
    //Some Other code
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('simplisto', 'simplisto_function');
```

Comment: Is extract in practice? I mean it is not obsolete?

Comment: Secondly how ill the selections work in the shortcode → `[simplisto]`

Comment: Look the line before the function

Comment: can you write this for `<h2>` also because from there I am fetching some data from theme customizer also?